TeamCity SMB Upload failing with STATUS_ACCESS_DENIED (0xc0000022)
I have a SMB upload step failing with an STATUS_ACCESS_DENIED (0xc0000022) error.
Looking at the event log of the target server I'm seeing :

The server received an unencrypted message from client when encryption
was required. Message was rejected.

Is there anyway to configure the SMB Upload step to use encryption?
